# How do I calculate a sum based on a column number which is the value of another cell?

Tags: google-sheets, microsoft-excel

[image]

I want to summarize in line 8, all the values in `A2:A6`. I want the function to get the column number from another cell (`B8`). Same for line 9. I want `A9` to summarize `b2:b6`.

**In other words:** How to add column number argument to `sum` function in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a job for the [`INDIRECT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en) function. For the sum in `A8`, use

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("R2C" & B8 & ":R5C" & B8; FALSE))
```

Likewise, for the sum in `A9`, use

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("R2C" & B9 & ":R5C" & B9; FALSE))
```

### Explanation:

`INDIRECT` lets you construct cell addresses from dynamic input, e.g. from other cells. It supports both *A1* notation (as in `A2`), and *R1C1* notation (like `R2C1`, for "row 2, column 1").

In this case, we are constructing a range string: `R2C1:R5C1`.

The `1` is the dynamic part, which is being picked up from cell `B8`. So all we have to do is concatenate the string from the parts `R2C`+ [contents of B8] + `:R5C`+ [contents of B8]. The `&` is the string concatenation operator in Google Sheets.

See [the example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iiaQ2QVEJAa30-TPjfETDoGROrWP_UWSoZKYIpW5vw0/edit?usp=sharing) I set up, and the documentation for [`INDIRECT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en).